# Integral over bounded $V$: $\idotsint _V\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{a_i-1}d^nx$

Tags: integration, gamma-function, infinite-product

Could anyone help me with this problem. I really cant see how I can tackle solving it? I think the result is to be expressed with Gamma function.

If $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded by the coordinate planes $x_i=0$ and the surface: $(\frac{x_1}{a_1})^{p_1}+(\frac{x_2}{a_2})^{p_2}+...+(\frac{x_n}{a_n})^{p_n}=1$, then compute the integral: $$\idotsint _V\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{a_i-1}d^nx$$

Comment: Hint: change variable to $y_k = \left(\frac{x_k}{a_k}\right)^{p_k}$ and turn it into a type-1 [Dirichlet integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletIntegrals.html)

Comment: I tried this change of variables and I got this: $\int \int ...\int _V\sum y_k\prod (y_k^{(a_k-1)/p_k}a_k^{a_k-1})d??$ Could you offer some more insight to the problem?

Comment: For type-1 Dirichlet's integral, we have: $$\int_{x_k \ge 0, \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \le 1} f\left(\sum_{k=1}^n t_k\right) \prod_{k=1}^n t_k^{\alpha_k-1}\prod_{k=1}^n dt_k = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n \Gamma(\alpha_k)}{\Gamma(\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k)}\int_0^1
f(\tau) \tau^{(\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k)-1} d\tau$$ Just replace $f(\tau)$ by the constant $1$ and you are done.

Comment: I get this: $\int \int ...\int _V\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{a_i-1}d^nx =\int \int ...\int _V\prod a_k^{a_k-1}*\sum y_k*\prod y_k^{(a_k-1)p_k}\prod dy_k , 

y_k=(x_k/a_k)^p_k $

Comment: But for the type-1 Dirichlet's integral I should have $y_k^{a_k-1}$ and not $y_k^{(a_k-1)p_k}$

Comment: and for my case $\int_0^1 f(\tau) \tau^{(\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k)-1} d\tau$ is $\int_{0}^{1}\tau ^{(\sum a_k)-1 }*(\prod a_k^{a_k-1})*\tau d\tau$ ?

Comment: @achillehui could you help me carry on with the computations because I m stuck...